# How to delete the Nuget packages folder as part of Clean Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, directory, solution

When I click on Build->Clean Solution in Visual Studio 2012, I'd like it to also delete several folders automatically to help with clean up solutions for archiving:

1. Nuget packages folder
2. bin and obj folders in C# project
3. Debug and DebugOut folders in C++ project

Is there a single location in my solution where I can specify all these folders manually?  If not, what is the next simplest way to accomplish this?

Note: I found some links to add the AfterClean tag to the C# project, but it doesn't seem like the right place to put delete commands that apply to folders outside of the C# project.

I also tried the CleanProject program, but it only worked on the C# project.

Comment: What do you mean by archiving?  If you are using source control like git for example, you can ignore files and folders in your .gitignore and they won't go into source control

Comment: Even when you have source control, it's occasionally handy to be able to clean the project, go to the solution folder, zip it up and save it for future reference.  It's also handy on small test projects where it doesn't necessarily makes sense to add them to source control.

Comment: Still not sure why source control isn't your solution.  You can create a branch or tag at the point in time for which you want to zip up the code base.

Source control is always valuable; even for 1 dev with a throw-away project.  What happens if your hard drive crashes or your laptop is stolen?

Source control is the answer to those questions and yours.

Comment: Ok.  Point taken.  Thanks for your thoughts.